# Блокировка номера Android

Tags: android, permissions

Делая приложение для блокировки номеров столкнулся с проблемой. Программа работает так как надо на эмуляторе (Android 8.0 Oreo API Level 26), но не работает на реальном устройстве c Android 9 выдавая ошибку:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapplication, PID: 3848
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.myapplication.InterceptCall: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3439)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:204)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1669)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6865)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:504)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at com.myapplication.InterceptCall.onReceive(InterceptCall.java:24)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3427)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:204) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1669) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6865) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:504) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Строка "*at com.myapplication.InterceptCall.onReceive(InterceptCall.java:24)*" ссылается на "*if (incomingNumber.equals("+1234567890")) {* " строку и текст "*a null object reference*" как бы намекает на отсутствие прав, но права приложению выданы (указаны в манифесте и рукаме активированы в настроках приложений). Права ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS, CALL_PHONE, READ_PHONE_STATE, READ_CALL_LOG.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">

    <activity android:name="com.myapplication.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.myapplication.InterceptCall">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.calldetectapplication.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

}

**InterceptCall.java**

```
package com.myapplication;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

import android.content.Context;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Binder;

import android.os.IBinder;

import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;


public class InterceptCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    String msg = "Phone state changed to " + state;

    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {
        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        msg += ". Incoming number is " + incomingNumber;
        if (incomingNumber.equals("+1234567890")) {
            msg= "Number : " + incomingNumber + " is BLOCKED";
            BreakCall();
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
private void BreakCall(){
    try {
        String serviceManagerName = "android.os.ServiceManager";
        String serviceManagerNativeName = "android.os.ServiceManagerNative";
        String telephonyName = "com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony";
        Class<?> telephonyClass;
        Class<?> telephonyStubClass;
        Class<?> serviceManagerClass;
        Class<?> serviceManagerNativeClass;
        Method telephonyEndCall;
        Object telephonyObject;
        Object serviceManagerObject;
        telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephonyName);
        telephonyStubClass = telephonyClass.getClasses()[0];
        serviceManagerClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerName);
        serviceManagerNativeClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerNativeName);
        Method getService = // getDefaults[29];
                serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);
        Method tempInterfaceMethod = serviceManagerNativeClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
        Binder tmpBinder = new Binder();
        tmpBinder.attachInterface(null, "fake");
        serviceManagerObject = tempInterfaceMethod.invoke(null, tmpBinder);
        IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(serviceManagerObject, "phone");
        Method serviceMethod = telephonyStubClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
        telephonyObject = serviceMethod.invoke(null, retbinder);
        telephonyEndCall = telephonyClass.getMethod("endCall");
        telephonyEndCall.invoke(telephonyObject);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Строка method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference Как бы намекает что вас объект не инициализирован

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. А почему этой ошибки нет на эмуляторе?

Comment: Сложно сказать, иногда так бывает

Comment: Может быть есть у кого рабочий код блокировки/отклонения входящего вызова? Поделитесь пожалуйста.